# How do I update a Post before it loads on the page on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

Hey there this is my first question on this platform, Thanks for having me.

I am busy building a website on Wordpress. I am listing attorneys in the country and having a Custom Post for each attorney made through CPT UI.

Using WPUF users can submit their own attorneys and that goes to ACF and then a Custom Post is made.
But the problem I am Having is that I have to manually update the post before it displays dynamically on my website.

Does anyone know of a work around for this, I am not experienced in php or html or js, but I suspect that some code will be required.

Thanks in advance.

And please say if you need further info, I'll be as helpful as I can be.

Comment: Can you describe more precisely this part > "But the problem I am Having is that I have to manually update the post before it displays dynamically on my website."

Comment: @AlexVand By that I mean that I have to go into my Custom Post on the Admin Panel and press the "Update" button, then only after I've done this does the information display on my post page.

Comment: How can they submit their own attorneys ?

Comment: @AlexVand They fill in a form that I made with WPUF, and the meta keys are the ACF fields, and then the post is made with those entries

Comment: And the problem is that the created post has not the "published" status ? So it's not appearing in front ?

Comment: @AlexVand It is "published" but for some reason the info only displays after updating

Comment: I can't fin any reason that makes your post not displayed. Do you have wrote to the plugin developpers ?

Comment: @AlexVand No I haven't, but good Idea, I will do that and get back to you. Thanks anyways :D